# Turn off IIS 6 HttpCompression for specific browsers

Tags: iis, browser, iis-6, silverlight-2.0, http-compression

I am having issues with IE6 (surprise) and HTTP Compression using IIS6.  I really don't want to turn off HTTP Compression for the site.  Is there a way to tell IIS6 to not compress responses to specific versions of browsers?  IE7 works fine.

EDIT:
My problem actually comes from Silverlight 2 consuming a WCF Service.  With compression turned on, Silverlight 2 on IE6 does not seem to work.  Here is [link](http://silverlight.net/themes/silverlight/forums/thread.aspx?ThreadID=42908&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to a discussion on silverlight.net.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Not built-in, that I know of, but you generally don't want to. If you do, you have to set the ‘Vary’ response header to include ‘User-Agent’, which degrades the efficacy of proxy caches and can confuse IE's own local cache.

I've not had any problem serving deflated content to IE6 (admittedly from Apache, but I don't think IIS's implementation is greatly different). What are the actual issues you're seeing?

The last browser I remember that had any trouble with gzip/deflate (but still passed Accept headers saying it wanted it) was Netscape 4, which soiled itself when it saw compressed stylesheets. But that's a browser that is thankfully no longer of concern to anyone.